# Error updating Amazon AMI with yum

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I am trying to `yum update` the EC2 server but fails. This is first time it happened what do i need to do to resolve this?

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXcomposite.x86_64 0:0.4.3-4.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.10.1-1.el7.ngx will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64
---> Package python27-futures.noarch 0:3.0.3-1.3.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
--> Running transaction check
---> Package kernel.x86_64 0:4.1.13-19.30.amzn1 will be erased
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.10.1-1.el7.ngx will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) for package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:nginx-1.10.1-1.el7.ngx.x86_64 (nginx)
           Requires: systemd
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have somehow managed to install `nginx` and the yum repository (provided by nginx.org) you have installed along with it is not compatible with Amazon Linux. It is intended for RHEL 7 or CentOS 7. Amazon Linux is not compatible with RHEL/CentOS, and packages for these often do not work on Amazon Linux.

To resolve the problem, launch a new instance with a supported operating system distribution such as RHEL 7 or CentOS 7, and install nginx on that instance.